# define variable number of vars to post with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

I have a number of tag inputs, defined dynamically and I hope to post the same number of vars as tags to the following ajax:
Only some or all of the `$('#tag_x').val()` will be defined

```
  $.ajax({
    url:'/ajax/defineTags/',
    type:'post',
    data:{
      tag_1:$('#tag_1').val(),
      tag_2:$('#tag_2').val(),
      tag_3:$('#tag_3').val(),
      tag_4:$('#tag_4').val(),
      tag_x:$('#tag_x').val(),
      tag_20:$('#tag_20').val()
    }
  }).always(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
```

My question is, do I use serialize?  It's not a standard form.
If so, please explain how?  I hope I have made myself clear.

Thanks!

Comment: What part of the code above doesn't work? You don't need serialize as you already have an object to pass under the data param. You may want to do some validation before you make the ajax call to determine if the field is defined and either skip that input or pass a default value. I would suggest the use of a loop in that case.

Comment: I will once I figure out how.  I tried something like definitions = {x1:'tag_x1',x2:'tag_x2',...} but that broke the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a friend suggested this and it works a treat:

```
for (var prop in response) {
      if (prop.indexOf('tag_') >= 0) {    // is a tag_ property
        tagNum = prop.substring(4);
        //~ console.log(tagNum);
        hasValue = response[prop] !== '';
        if(response[prop] !== ''){
          //~ alert(tagNum+response[prop]);
          $('#tags-select').append('<option value="'+tagNum+'">'+response[prop]+'</option>');
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var data = $('input[id^="tag_"]').serialize();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vLjyw2ks/4/)

to Add data to serialize

```
var data = $('input[id^="tag"]').serialize();
var Add_Data = data+'&id='+$('#tags-id').text();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vLjyw2ks/5/)

for more complex

```
var data = $('input[id^="tag"]').serialize();
$('span[id^="tags"]').each(function(){
    var ThisText = $(this).text();
    var ThisId = $(this).attr('id');
    var add_Data = ThisId+'='+ThisText;
    data = data+'&'+ add_Data;
});
$('div').text(data);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vLjyw2ks/8/)

and in ajax use

```
data: data
```

something you should know about **.serialize()**

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual
>   form controls, such as , , and : $( "input,
>   textarea, select" ).serialize();
>
> and the output should be something like this
>
> single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1

something you should know about **.serializeArray()**

> The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects,
>   ready to be encoded as a JSON string. It operates on a jQuery
>   collection of forms and/or form controls. The controls can be of
>   several types:
>
> the output
>
> [   {
>       name: "a",
>       value: "1"   },   {
>       name: "b",
>       value: "2"   },   {
>       name: "c",
>       value: "3"   },   {
>       name: "d",
>       value: "4"   },   {
>       name: "e",
>       value: "5"   } ]

Comment: Please pardon my dust, I am troubleshooting other, related problems - I appreciate your help.

Comment: How do I include one more array element to the serialize? Like id:$('#tags-id').text(),

Comment: @phpmydev sorry for delay in reply ...  try to know the shape of serialize  so in demo the output is (nothing1=yes&nothing2=no&nothing3=Ok)  so to add another values to serialize it should be id=$('#tags-id').text() ..  so in your case you can use     data+'&id='+$('#tags-id').text() .... http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vLjyw2ks/5/

Comment: @phpmydev you can check my updated answer .. I think it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.serializeArray()`

```
var data_arr = $('[id^=#tag_]').serializeArray();
$.ajax({
    url:'/ajax/defineTags/',
    type:'post',
    data:data_arr
  }).always(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
```